# Insterting avl tree

Tags: java, random, numbers, avl-tree

I want to insert a tree from a randomized array. Here is my code:

```
int[] startValues=new int [100];
for(int i=0;i<startValues.length;i++){
startValues[i]=rnd.nextInt(10);
tree.insert(startValues[i]);
```

and then I see this warning:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at myproject.AVLTree.singleWithLeftChild(AVLTree.java:77)
at myproject.AVLTree.insert(AVLTree.java:47)
at project.Test.main(Test.java:25)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: well what does a nullpointerexception mean ? youre trying to acces a object somewhere where none exists. Could you post the code of 'singleWithLeftChild' ?

Comment: public BinaryNode singleWithLeftChild(BinaryNode k2){
     BinaryNode k1 = k2.getLeft();
     k2.setLeft(k1.getRight());
     if(k2.getParent() != null){
       if(k2.getParent().getLeft() == k2){
         
         k2.getParent().setLeft(k1);
       } else {
         k2.getParent().setRight(k1);
       }
     }
     k1.setRight(k2);
     k2.reBalance();
     k1.reBalance();
     if(k1.getParent() == null){
       _root = k1;
     }
     return k1;
   }

here is my code but if a filled array not using random,the code is working. i don't understand